# PL/SQL - will statements execute only once a procedure is completed?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hopefully this is a simple question. Say I have a block like this:

```
BEGIN
  a_random_procedure ('input','output');

  ... DML statements ...
END;
```

Question: Will `DML statements` execute only after `a_random_procedure` is completed? For that matter, will anything after `a_random_procedure` execute only after it is completed?

ADD-ON: What about when `a_random_procedure` is executing another procedure within it?

Comment: Yes. Statements execution is sequential.

Comment: Hi, I have edited the post and included some more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the "DML statements" will execute only after "a_random_procedure" is completed. 
 If you have another procedure within it, the first procedure will wait until the procedure within it is completed too. 
 In any moment when you call another procedure or function, the next code line will wait until the procedure or function called before, has finished his execution

Answer (score 2):

PL/SQL is like in name of launguage - procedural, so the answer for Your question is yes, dml will be executed after procedure finish, even if procedure calls other procs/functions. Yo can take care about case when Your procedure crash, then it will not be completed, and then thera are 2 options, if the exception in procedure is handled then Your dml will be executed. If exception is not handled, it will be populated level up, in this case to Your anonymous block, and crash(stop) it as well and it will not execute DML.

Comment: To be accurate, the fact that PL/SQL supports procedural coding doesn't bear on this question. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_programming